# How to access device gmail account password from Android Applications

Tags: android

Iam developing one Android Application, which requires to send email messages. So I want to get Default Password set by the user in his device from my code. Is there any way. I have used JavaMail API's for sending messages. Thanks in advance.

---

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
    String SenderAddress = null, Password = null;

    for (Account account : accounts) 
    {
        if(account.name.endsWith("gmail.com"))
        {
            SenderAddress = account.name;
            Password = ?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

> So I want to get Default Password set by the user in my code.

I am sure this kind of password fetching functinality is not available. Because if i am successful in fetching somebody's password then i will sure do and then i am able to access that user's gmail account easily.

I hope you got my point.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Then how to send Email in a background.

Answer (score 1):

According Optimus and the information in the link, It is Google which manages all the process of signing into a Google account, then neither the App nor the Website have access to the password.

I think for security reasons it is not possible and I hope so :D

Comment: Which link are you referring to in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Paresh is correct, but you could use Google open id, like stackoverflow does . Check this link http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

Comment: Since Iam using JavaMail API,s for sending Mail, while creating Sender object it asks for username and password. Syntax is GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username", "password"); Is any other ways to send email. Pls let me Know.